# Magento getUrl showing cached url

Tags: php, magento, url, caching, categories

I have added a custom block that shows the sub categories of a parent category. as follows.

```
<?php
$_helper    = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();

echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getName(), 'name');
$categoriess = $_category->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
    ->addIdFilter($_category->getChildren())
?>
<ul class="subcategories">
<?php foreach ($categoriess as $categoryy): ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $categoryy->getUrl() ?>"><img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog' . DS . 'category' . DS . $categoryy->getThumbnail() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($categoryy->getName()) ?>"   />
            <span><?php echo $categoryy->getName() ?></span></a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

This code correctly shows a list of the sub categories within the parent category. However when I navigate to one of these subcategories something weird happens.

**The Problem**

Parent category = CAR MAKES
sub categories = AUDI, FORD, VAUXHALL

Using the above code I correctly receive a list of the sub categories above. After flushing the cache, if I were to navigate to AUDI, the url will correctly generate for example:

```
 mysite.com/CAR MAKES/Audi.html
```

This is fine, however if i then go back and navigate to FORD the url at the top of the page DOES display as

```
 mysite.com/CAR MAKES/Ford.html
```

**BUT**

if I echo the url on the genrated page with this code:

```
<?php $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(); echo $currentUrl; ?>
```

it will always display

```
mysite.com/CAR MAKES/Audi.html
```

Even if I navigate to FORD, or VAUXHALL the url that is echo'd is /Audi.html, despite the url at the top of the page displaying correctly.

I am completely lost as to why this is happening. I am trying to produce a product list for each car make and model, but once you have navigated to one make and model, it will always display those results when navigating to another make and model. Unless I flush the cache, in which case the first time I navigate to a make and model it shows correctly, and after that the error repeats.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your layout update.

```
<block type="core/template" template="your-template-path.phtml" name="template-name" ><action method="setCacheLifetime"><s>null</s></action></block>
```

Comment: Ok i have tried adding this to the category layout update but with no effect.

The cmd block that displays the sub categories of the product is called through this code:


         {{block type="catalog/navigation" template="catalog/category/sub.phtml"}} 

Not sure if this makes any difference